# How to view contents of NSDictionary variable in Xcode debugger?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, debugging

Is there a way to view the key/value pairs of a NSDictionary variable through the Xcode debugger?  Here's the extent of information when it is fully expanded in the variable window:

```
Variable  Value      Summary
jsonDict  0x45c540   4 key/value pairs
 NSObject {...}
  isa     0xa06e0720
```

I was expecting it to show me each element of the dictionary (similar to an array variable).

Answer (score 140, accepted):

In the gdb window you can use `po` to inspect the object.

given:

```
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setObject:@"foo" forKey:@"bar"];
[dict setObject:@"fiz" forKey:@"buz"];
```

setting a breakpoint after the objects are added you can inspect what is in the dictionary

```
(gdb) po dict
{
  bar = foo;
  buz = fiz;
}
```

Of course these are `NSString` objects that print nicely. YMMV with other complex objects.

Comment: Hi! What is gdb? What is po? Not sure to understand... Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Ok so I found out that GDB stands for GNU debugger and is in fact the debugger window of Xcode. Now I need to find what is po

Comment: OK! So gdb is in fact a prompt in the Console, where you can input commands. By typing "po object_name" you got the object content printed in the console.

Comment: po is an alias for print-object

Comment: Wonderful! Equivalant to "echo var_dump()" or "print_r()" in PHP.

Comment: I have a JSON format file i used NSJSONSerialization for this file and stored in NSDictionary how can I view the objects in the Dictionary

Comment: Thanks for commenting with what gdb and po stand for, @Martin.

Comment: so....is this still the preferred way to do this? i'm thinking of IDEs like Eclipse, which pretty-print values for all public members of an object straight into the Variables panel.  this functionality requires typing in a command in Xcode?

Comment: With Xcode 4 you pretty much get the above (i.e. a debugger console pane now powered by lldb rather than gdb), as well as being able to get a tooltip showing object values if you hover over the var in question. Xcode isn't my normal thing so I don't remember if the tooltip thing is new or when it might have ben added.

Comment: You can also put `po obj` in a breakpoint and then have the process continue automatically after the breakpoint. That way you don't have to stope and type it every time.

Answer (score 30):

You can right-click any object (ObjC or Core Foundation) variable and select “Print Description to Console” (also in Run->Variables View). This prints the result the obejct’s `-debugDescription` method, which by default calls `-description`. Unfortunately, `NSDictionary` overrides this to produce a bunch of internal data the you generally don’t care about, so in this specific case craigb’s solution is better.

The displayed keys and values also use `-description`, so if you want useful information about your objects in collections and elsewhere, overriding `-description` is a must. I generally implement it along these lines, to match the format of the default `NSObject` implementation:

```
-(NSString *) description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@ %p>{foo: %@}", [self class], self, [self foo]];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use CFShow()

```
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setObject:@"foo" forKey:@"bar"];
[dict setObject:@"fiz" forKey:@"buz"];
CFShow(dict);
```

In output you will see

```
{
  bar = foo;
  buz = fiz;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

XCode 4.6 has added the following functionality which may be helpful to you

```
The elements of NSArray and NSDictionary objects can now be inspected in the Xcode debugger
```

Now you can inspect these object types without having to print the entire object in the console. Enjoy!

Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_6.html

Comment: This is buggy for me -- only shows part of my NSDictionary

Answer (score 1):

Click on your dict, then click on the little "i" icon, it should do the job :-)
[image: Xcode5, view the value of a dict]

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to print these in a breakpoint action in modern XCode (yes, I am 10 years after the original post!) use the following breakpoint expression in a "Log Message" action:

@myDictionary.description@

Below is a screenshot of my breakpoint action where the variable event is an NSString and the variable contextData is the NSDictionary that I am logging the contents of:
[image]:

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [NSLog](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSLog).

Also you can go in Debug area or xcode, then find out `All Variables, Registers, Globals and Statics` then select your variable. Right click on it. Then select `Print description of "...."`

Hope it helps!