# Is it possible to type in variables in the Xcode debugger to check what they are?

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging

I've done my fair share of searching, but the problem lies in the fact that I don't know all the nomenclature surrounding the debugger, so I'm unsure of what this function is called.

In my programming class, we use Visual Studio.  In it's debugger, you can type in a variable name at any point and see what it's value is.

Is there a parallel version of this in Xcode?  I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Add a breakpoint to the point where you would like to check the value. When it stops there, click on console screen. Type the following:

```
po yourVariableName
```

**Option 2:**

Click on "Show debug Area". Now tap on "Show Variable Area". You can see values on run time for each variable in action.

For more detailed reading, read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735156/xcode-debugger-view-value-of-variable).
[image: Hand drawn circles finallyyyy]

Comment: I actually have been using Option 2 for a while now, but the issue is, it doesn't always display variables for some reason.  I can't remember what the issue was in the past, but there have been several instances where the debugger didn't display a certain variable.  I know that it currently isn't displaying elements in an array in a function..... its just showing the first element - Subscript 0, but nothing else.  Any reason why it doesn't show these?  Option 1 works nicely though.  Thanks.

Comment: @joe_04_04 Have you tried hovering mouse over your array variable and then clicking the little eye icon? To print description? Also on breakpoint, you can go to line of code itself, hover over the variable and click the same eye button. It will print complete array.

Comment: I actually never knew that.. I've only been using Xcode for 3 months or so now and am learning more everyday.  I actually just now learned you can edit a variable's name globally with one action... wow, that will save me so much time... but back to your answer with option 2, I did not know hovering over the eye would show all the elements... the issue still persists though, it works when trying to display elements in an array in the main function, but not when trying to display elements in another function outside of the main.  Anyway, I suppose typing it out is not so bad.  Thank you!

Comment: @joe_04_04 Variable Area will show only the variables which are in execution scope. I have found a solid question with very good and in detail answers for you. Hopefully, they will nicely clear your concepts about it. Also you don't have to type it all out, e.g. if your variable name is `myVar` and it is accessible in current exe scope, you only have to type `m` and xcode will show you list of all vars starting with name m.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This information has been helpful.  I did mark your answer as the solution.

This is what I meant by it doesn't show the elements of an array in a function.  Is it because it is pointing to the array in main?

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5129928/Screen%20Shot%202015-11-11%20at%2012.40.16%20AM.png

Comment: strange. your `Number` array is in execution scope. It should display. Right click on it in `variable area` you will get something like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/TkMMl.png. click on print Number. (I have never worked with cpp on xcode so I really can only guess what's going on there).

Comment: I did what you tried.  Heres a cleaner version of code.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5129928/Screen%20Shot%202015-11-11%20at%201.38.10%20AM.png

When I print it from the main, it displays just fine, but when I print it from the function, it doesn't.  Oh well, I'll just chalk it up as some oddity of Xcode.  I appreciate all your help.  This community has been great.