# NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:inSection: returning nonsensical value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsindexpath

What I mean by 'nonsensical' is that the item becomes a totally different integer from the one I pass in, and even after reading the iOS documentation, I don't know why.

```
NSIndexPath* iPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:4 inSection:0];
```

I set a breakpoint immediately after that line, and I see

[image]

What could possibly be happening under the hood?  Have I done something wrong?  I've tried other things such as casting the '4' or passing in a variable, and always I end up with something much larger than the index I pass in.  This is causing problems obviously as I need to use this NSIndexPath to access a specific element in a UICollectionView, and just in case this debug window is showing me some coded or hashed value, I tried passing the path into

```
[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:iPath];
```

and it returns nil, likely because iPath's item doesn't exist in the collectionView.  Could someone please help provide some insight into how I can create a valid NSIndexPath for my fifth item?

Comment: `[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:4 inSection:0]` is right to for fifth element in section 0.You may use `po iPath` in lldb. Then it will log the right value

Comment: I see. So the debugger variable window's [0] and [1] and not item and section, respectively?

Comment: Maybe take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112796

Comment: As mentioned by Leo , you should check the value in the console it will show you the correct value like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/05PDT.png. for the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` there may no cell at the 5th but you are trying to get it or may be some other problem

Comment: I verified using po.  Thank you for pointing that out.  The other stackoverflow link talks about NSDictionary, and I was able to see those in the debug variable watch window fine, but the NSIndex values just don't seem to have much immediate meaning.  I'll post back about the reason for the nil value..

Comment: The collectionView was returning nil likely because the item was not fully visible (only the top four elements are on screen, with the next two cut-off)... so I guess that answers that.  Apologies for the ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

Leo's response was the correct answer.  The values I was seeing in the debugger's variables panel were not directly tied to the section and item as I originally thought.  His suggestion to use

```
po iPath
```

in the debug console yielded the proper values, and I tweaked my breakpoint by right clicking it and entering a command to print this information automatically.

The reason collectionView returned a nil cell when given this index was simply because the cell was partially offscreen.  If I scroll it fully onscreen, then the value returned is legitimate.

As a side note, I was trying to get the coordinates of an off-screen element on purpose so I could animate to its coordinates, so this answer does not directly help, but it clears up my misconception.  I ultimately solved my problem by storing the coordinates of the desired cell and using that instead of trying to backtrack through the index path.

Answer (score -3):

You may want to try this

```
NSIndexPath *indexP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:0] ;
```